# Using PredicateBuilder to match part of word

Tags: entity-framework-4, linqkit

I'm using LinqKit predicate Builder to find a record. 
I need to match the same as Like %word%

p -> is Customer Class with FirstName, LastName ect....

but when I use:

```
predicate = predicate.And(p => p.FirstName.Contains(searchCriteria.FirstName));
```

I get only Exact match. 
how can I change the code to get partial match (if I look for dani I want to get both "dani" and "daniel" )

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try with `IndexOf`?

```
predicate = predicate.And(p => p.FirstName.IndexOf(searchCriteria.FirstName) > -1);
```

Comment: Although it looks like a good solution, it doesn't work... (even on exact match)

Comment: I've found the problem somewhere else in the code. this line was correct as well and it equals to contains. thanks.